# is it possible to read the text of a li using Xpath with different attributes?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am aware that I can directly use:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//ul[3]/li/ul/li[7]")).Text
```

to get the text .. but I am trying get the text by using Xpath and combination of different attributes like `text()`, `contains()` etc.

```
//ul[3]/li/ul/li//[text()='My Data']
```

Please suggest me different ways that I can handle this ... except the one I mentioned.

```
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope selectedTreeElement" ng-click="orgSelCtrl.selectUserSessionOrg(child);" ng-class="{selectedTreeElement: child.organizationId == orgSelCtrl.SelectedOrg.organizationId}" ng-repeat="child in node.childOrgs" style="background-color: transparent;"> My Data </li>
```

Comment: My Html looks as below <li class="ng-binding ng-scope selectedTreeElement" ng-click="orgSelCtrl.selectUserSessionOrg(child);" ng-class="selectedTreeElement: child.organizationId == orgSelCtrl.SelectedOrg.organizationId}" ng-repeat="child in node.childOrgs" style="background-color: transparent;"> My Data </li>

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have extra "/" in your xpath and you miss dot:
//ul[3]/li/ul/li//[text()='My Data']

try this:
.//ul[3]/li/ul/li[text()='My Data']

BUT you are use xpath only for find elements, but not for reading its attributes. If you need to read attribute or text inside of it, you need to use selenium after search.

Answer (score 0):

`.Text` of a `WebElement` would just *return* you the text of an element.

If you want to make expectations about the text, check the `text()` inside the XPath expression, e.g.:

```
//ul[3]/li/ul/li[text()='My Data']
```

or, using [`contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains):

```
//ul[3]/li/ul/li[contains(text(), 'My Data')]
```

There are other functions you can make use of, see [Functions - XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions).

You can also combine it with other conditions. For instance:

```
//ul[3]/li/ul/li[contains(@class, 'selectedTreeElement') and contains(text(), 'My Data')]
```